# Angular Js : onchange in directive at class attribute is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

controldirective.js

```
  function validVehicleyear($scope, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',                
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                element.bind('change', function () {
                    console.log('here in validVehicleyear');
                    $http.get('api.php/'+scope.ngModel)
                            .then(function (response) {
                                $scope.answers.VehicleMake = response.data;
                            });
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

[plnkr.co/edit/BFGXr7LNAe0KvQipj9JJ?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/BFGXr7LNAe0KvQipj9JJ?p=preview)

I wrote a directive validVehicleyear on class at Vehicle year question, this i want to call on change of year and set new options for Vehicle make, but it not working.

`Class="form-control **valid-vehicleyear** ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched"`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare your directive function

`.directive('validVehicleyear', validVehicleyear)`

http://plnkr.co/edit/9bGXO96s0BJVik7VecFU?p=preview

Comment: thanks . I updated plunker. you  did changes in changed <select valid-vehicleyear in controlDirective.js, I can not line like that, So I created a class on which i want to create a directive.

Comment: restrict: 'C', works to cretae directive but its not working

Comment: @pandudas yes, I mistook C for comment directive. But regardless the plunker works. An alert popsup when you change the year. EDIT: oh I see what you mean

Comment: Yes I missed to add above line in plunker. At the final I want to make it working with restrict: 'C', why it is directive not working on class. What I am missing.

Comment: Right, I couldn't figure why it doesn't work with class. Maybe a conflicting class name css vs directive? I never use directive as css classes. I find it confusing and very bad practice. You should probably refactor your code.

Comment: If I skip classes then how can I create a new dynamic attribute. Each form question should have unique attribute. So that I could apply validation or any change event on specific element only.

Comment: see my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821980/how-to-write-directive-on-class-in-angular-js/38823610#38823610